# Can you give some advice on designing my Spark Stream source?

Tags: python, apache-spark, hdfs

I will try to describe my requirement as best as I can. But please feel free to ask me if it still unclear.

## The environment

I have 5 nodes (will be more in the future). Each of them generating a big CSV file (about 1 to 2 GB) every 5 minutes. I need to use apache spark stream to process these CSV files in five minutes. So these 5 files are my input DStream source.

## What I planning to do

I plan to use textFileStream like below:

```
ssc.textFileStream(dataDirectory)
```

Every 5 minutes I will put those CSV in a directory on the HDFS. Then use the above function to generate inputDStream.

## The problem of the above way

the textFileStream need one complete file instead of 5 files. I do not know how to merge files in HDFS

## Question

1. Can you tell me how to merge files in hdfs by python?
2. Do you have any better suggestion than my way? Please also advice me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can always read the files in a directory using wild card character.
 That should not be a problem. Which means at any given time your DStream's RDD is the merged result of all files at that given time.

As far as the approach goes, your's is simple and works.

NB: The only thing you should be careful about is the atomicity of the CSV  files themselves. Your files should go to the folder(which you are watching  for incoming file) as `mv` not `copy`

Thanks
Manas

Comment: Thanks @Manas. But to construct the DStream. I need to use the textFileStream API. And this API is accepting a directory as parameter. So could you give some code example please?

Comment: Yes, `textFileStream` takes a directory as a parameter. So files coming to that directory at any given point can all be part of an RDD at any given time. I don't have textFileStream example with me right now. But I will keep looking for it and post it when I find it.

Comment: Actually we know that DStream is constructed by a series of RDD. So we can read files in a directory with wild card every 5 minutes, then construct DStream with these RDD. But I do not know a proper way to construct DStream with these RDD. Do you have any idea?

Comment: Please take a look at this [link](https://github.com/eBay/Spark/blob/master/examples/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/examples/streaming/QueueStream.scala). You can create a DStream from your RDD's.